# setting up the first yii project

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to open my first yii application
just when I write localhost
it gives this error :

> Warning: require_once(C:\inetpub\wwwroot/../yii-1.1.21.733ac5/yii-1.1.21.733ac5/framework/yii.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php on line 13
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot/../yii-1.1.21.733ac5/yii-1.1.21.733ac5/framework/yii.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php on line 13

which and where the file for the yii.app I must put it ?

Here's what in the index :

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'C:\yii\yii-1.1.21.733ac5\yii-1.1.21.733ac5\framework\yii.php';

$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the path given to load the Yii framework:

```php
// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'C:\yii\yii-1.1.21.733ac5\yii-1.1.21.733ac5\framework\yii.php';
```

The `dirname(__FILE__)` is the [`dirname`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) (parent directory path) of your `index.php`, so you shouldn't append an absolute path to it, but a relative one, e.g.:

```php
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../yii/framework/yii.php';
```

Or just use an absolute path:

```php
$yii='C:\yii\yii-1.1.21.733ac5\yii-1.1.21.733ac5\framework\yii.php';
```

Are you sure the folder `yii-1.1.21.733ac5` should be in the path twice?

Finally, please note that Yii 1 has reached its lifetime and only receives security fixes. You should definitely use Yii 2 for new projects.